# Error when using $lookup and $geoWithin in MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, spatial

I am working on a MongoDB aggregation pipeline where I need to perform a lookup and filter documents based on the $geoWithin operator. However, I am encountering the following error:

MongoServerError: unknown geo specifier: $geometry: "$$roadGeometry"

Here is the code I'm using:

```
db.manchaster_lines.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "properties.highway": "service"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "manchaster_polygons_v2",
      let: {
        roadGeometry: "$geometry"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "properties.building": "house"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            geometry: {
              $geoWithin: {
                $geometry: "$$roadGeometry"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "houses"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "houses.0": { $exists: true }
    }
  }
]);
```

In this code, I'm trying to find the service roads (manchaster_lines collection) that are geowithin the houses (manchaster_polygons_v2 collection) using the $geoWithin operator.
The data of manchaster_polygons_v2 is:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40a8411cd41e3f55347d3"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 36061,
    "osm_id": null,
    "osm_way_id": "367080976",
    "name": null,
    "type": null,
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "house",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": null
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.0858817,
            53.45525
          ],
          [
            -2.0859629,
            53.4552344
          ],
          [
            -2.0861388,
            53.4552005
          ],
          [
            -2.0865083,
            53.4559055
          ],
          [
            -2.0859874,
            53.4559959
          ],
          [
            -2.0859281,
            53.455888
          ],
          [
            -2.0860256,
            53.455869
          ],
          [
            -2.0860478,
            53.4559096
          ],
          [
            -2.0863239,
            53.4558479
          ],
          [
            -2.0860472,
            53.4552979
          ],
          [
            -2.0859997,
            53.4553075
          ],
          [
            -2.0859257,
            53.4553223
          ],
          [
            -2.0858817,
            53.45525
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40aab11cd41e3f556f4f8"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 276592,
    "osm_id": null,
    "osm_way_id": "846655907",
    "name": null,
    "type": null,
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "house",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": "\"addr:city\"=>\"Stockport\",\"addr:housenumber\"=>\"9\",\"addr:postcode\"=>\"SK3 8EH\",\"addr:street\"=>\"Abbeyfield Close\",\"house\"=>\"semi-detached\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.1643399,
            53.3965198
          ],
          [
            -2.1642383,
            53.396532
          ],
          [
            -2.1641955,
            53.3965373
          ],
          [
            -2.1641941,
            53.3965332
          ],
          [
            -2.1641743,
            53.3964733
          ],
          [
            -2.1642145,
            53.3964685
          ],
          [
            -2.1643201,
            53.3964554
          ],
          [
            -2.1643399,
            53.3965198
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40ab111cd41e3f55776f4"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 310304,
    "osm_id": null,
    "osm_way_id": "910662985",
    "name": null,
    "type": null,
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "house",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": "\"addr:city\"=>\"Salford\",\"addr:postcode\"=>\"M5 3NZ\",\"addr:street\"=>\"Hulton Street\",\"building:levels\"=>\"3\",\"building:material\"=>\"brick\",\"roof:material\"=>\"tar_paper\",\"roof:shape\"=>\"flat\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.2807681,
            53.4728919
          ],
          [
            -2.2807737,
            53.4728929
          ],
          [
            -2.2808166,
            53.4729005
          ],
          [
            -2.2807925,
            53.4729488
          ],
          [
            -2.2807493,
            53.4729411
          ],
          [
            -2.2806719,
            53.4729274
          ],
          [
            -2.2806961,
            53.4728791
          ],
          [
            -2.2807389,
            53.4728867
          ],
          [
            -2.2807419,
            53.4728809
          ],
          [
            -2.2807448,
            53.4728751
          ],
          [
            -2.280774,
            53.4728802
          ],
          [
            -2.2807681,
            53.4728919
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40ab211cd41e3f557976e"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 316458,
    "osm_id": null,
    "osm_way_id": "924550562",
    "name": null,
    "type": null,
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "house",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": "\"addr:city\"=>\"Salford\",\"addr:postcode\"=>\"M5 3GE\",\"addr:street\"=>\"Hulton Street\",\"building:levels\"=>\"3\",\"building:material\"=>\"brick\",\"roof:material\"=>\"tar_paper\",\"roof:shape\"=>\"flat\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.2795054,
            53.4726476
          ],
          [
            -2.2794744,
            53.4727103
          ],
          [
            -2.2794453,
            53.4727052
          ],
          [
            -2.2794168,
            53.4727002
          ],
          [
            -2.2794478,
            53.4726375
          ],
          [
            -2.2794761,
            53.4726425
          ],
          [
            -2.2795054,
            53.4726476
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40a7d11cd41e3f552bc03"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 109,
    "osm_id": "1870212",
    "osm_way_id": null,
    "name": null,
    "type": "multipolygon",
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "school",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": null
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.3435857,
            53.4592804
          ],
          [
            -2.3436441,
            53.4597169
          ],
          [
            -2.3436228,
            53.4597179
          ],
          [
            -2.3433055,
            53.459733
          ],
          [
            -2.3433185,
            53.4598307
          ],
          [
            -2.3429813,
            53.4598467
          ],
          [
            -2.3429634,
            53.4597126
          ],
          [
            -2.3429891,
            53.4597113
          ],
          [
            -2.3429356,
            53.4593112
          ],
          [
            -2.3429822,
            53.459309
          ],
          [
            -2.3435857,
            53.4592804
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            -2.3434544,
            53.4595959
          ],
          [
            -2.3434284,
            53.4594284
          ],
          [
            -2.3431471,
            53.4594439
          ],
          [
            -2.343173,
            53.4596114
          ],
          [
            -2.3434544,
            53.4595959
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40a7d11cd41e3f552bbe6"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 83,
    "osm_id": "1832404",
    "osm_way_id": null,
    "name": null,
    "type": "multipolygon",
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "hospital",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": null
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.1321242,
            53.3843368
          ],
          [
            -2.1317791,
            53.3841787
          ],
          [
            -2.1318196,
            53.3841472
          ],
          [
            -2.1317641,
            53.3841218
          ],
          [
            -2.1316666,
            53.3841974
          ],
          [
            -2.131375,
            53.3840633
          ],
          [
            -2.1315793,
            53.3839092
          ],
          [
            -2.131496,
            53.3838704
          ],
          [
            -2.1313248,
            53.3840013
          ],
          [
            -2.131114,
            53.3839033
          ],
          [
            -2.1312874,
            53.3837688
          ],
          [
            -2.1311861,
            53.3837223
          ],
          [
            -2.1313444,
            53.3835995
          ],
          [
            -2.1314449,
            53.3836457
          ],
          [
            -2.1315871,
            53.3835354
          ],
          [
            -2.1315832,
            53.3835184
          ],
          [
            -2.1315748,
            53.3834846
          ],
          [
            -2.131619,
            53.3834808
          ],
          [
            -2.1316766,
            53.3834758
          ],
          [
            -2.1318768,
            53.383569
          ],
          [
            -2.1318813,
            53.3835957
          ],
          [
            -2.1320111,
            53.3836566
          ],
          [
            -2.1320577,
            53.3836523
          ],
          [
            -2.1322729,
            53.3837508
          ],
          [
            -2.1322715,
            53.3837796
          ],
          [
            -2.1323833,
            53.3838309
          ],
          [
            -2.1324326,
            53.3838257
          ],
          [
            -2.1324567,
            53.3838366
          ],
          [
            -2.1324929,
            53.3838094
          ],
          [
            -2.1326597,
            53.3838851
          ],
          [
            -2.1326252,
            53.3839124
          ],
          [
            -2.132649,
            53.3839231
          ],
          [
            -2.1326519,
            53.3839479
          ],
          [
            -2.1326561,
            53.3839845
          ],
          [
            -2.1325726,
            53.3839887
          ],
          [
            -2.1325289,
            53.3840227
          ],
          [
            -2.1324307,
            53.3840987
          ],
          [
            -2.1325325,
            53.3841467
          ],
          [
            -2.1323716,
            53.3842731
          ],
          [
            -2.1322666,
            53.3842263
          ],
          [
            -2.1322433,
            53.3842444
          ],
          [
            -2.1321242,
            53.3843368
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            -2.1322283,
            53.384004
          ],
          [
            -2.1323574,
            53.3839033
          ],
          [
            -2.1323562,
            53.3838789
          ],
          [
            -2.1323087,
            53.3838561
          ],
          [
            -2.1322622,
            53.3838592
          ],
          [
            -2.1322573,
            53.3838329
          ],
          [
            -2.1322079,
            53.3838116
          ],
          [
            -2.1321731,
            53.3838167
          ],
          [
            -2.1320419,
            53.383919
          ],
          [
            -2.1322283,
            53.384004
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            -2.1318423,
            53.3838224
          ],
          [
            -2.1319714,
            53.3837217
          ],
          [
            -2.1319702,
            53.3836973
          ],
          [
            -2.1319228,
            53.3836745
          ],
          [
            -2.1318762,
            53.3836776
          ],
          [
            -2.1318713,
            53.3836513
          ],
          [
            -2.131822,
            53.38363
          ],
          [
            -2.1317872,
            53.3836351
          ],
          [
            -2.131656,
            53.3837374
          ],
          [
            -2.1318423,
            53.3838224
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a40a7d11cd41e3f552bc20"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 144,
    "osm_id": "2309615",
    "osm_way_id": null,
    "name": "Manchester Royal Eye Hospital",
    "type": "multipolygon",
    "aeroway": null,
    "amenity": null,
    "admin_leve": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "boundary": null,
    "building": "hospital",
    "craft": null,
    "geological": null,
    "historic": null,
    "land_area": null,
    "landuse": null,
    "leisure": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "military": null,
    "natural": null,
    "office": null,
    "place": null,
    "shop": null,
    "sport": null,
    "tourism": null,
    "other_tags": "\"operator\"=>\"Central Manchester University Hospitals\",\"wikidata\"=>\"Q6747495\",\"wikipedia\"=>\"en:Manchester Royal Eye Hospital\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [
            -2.2237188,
            53.4615344
          ],
          [
            -2.2237818,
            53.4615226
          ],
          [
            -2.2255587,
            53.461041
          ],
          [
            -2.2257801,
            53.4613315
          ],
          [
            -2.2260867,
            53.4616785
          ],
          [
            -2.2259076,
            53.4617337
          ],
          [
            -2.2256554,
            53.4618294
          ],
          [
            -2.2257628,
            53.4619272
          ],
          [
            -2.2254152,
            53.4620627
          ],
          [
            -2.2251856,
            53.4618519
          ],
          [
            -2.2241776,
            53.4621215
          ],
          [
            -2.2240778,
            53.4621473
          ],
          [
            -2.2239706,
            53.4619983
          ],
          [
            -2.2240063,
            53.4619894
          ],
          [
            -2.2239661,
            53.4619433
          ],
          [
            -2.2240257,
            53.4619237
          ],
          [
            -2.2237188,
            53.4615344
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            -2.2246299,
            53.4615949
          ],
          [
            -2.224345,
            53.461669
          ],
          [
            -2.2244009,
            53.4617451
          ],
          [
            -2.2246857,
            53.461671
          ],
          [
            -2.2246299,
            53.4615949
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}]
```

The data of manchaster_lines is:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6847b7f13446c43651c"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 159323,
    "osm_id": "846655902",
    "name": null,
    "highway": "service",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": 0,
    "other_tags": "\"access\"=>\"private\",\"service\"=>\"driveway\",\"tunnel\"=>\"building_passage\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.1642383,
          53.396532
        ],
        [
          -2.1642145,
          53.3964685
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6877b7f13446c43a720"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 176220,
    "osm_id": "917390144",
    "name": null,
    "highway": "service",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": 0,
    "other_tags": "\"tunnel\"=>\"building_passage\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.0859997,
          53.4553075
        ],
        [
          -2.0859629,
          53.4552344
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6877b7f13446c43ac90"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 177616,
    "osm_id": "924545964",
    "name": null,
    "highway": "service",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": -10,
    "other_tags": "\"lit\"=>\"yes\",\"surface\"=>\"asphalt\",\"tunnel\"=>\"yes\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.2807737,
          53.4728929
        ],
        [
          -2.2807493,
          53.4729411
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6877b7f13446c43ac93"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 177619,
    "osm_id": "924545967",
    "name": null,
    "highway": "service",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": -10,
    "other_tags": "\"lit\"=>\"yes\",\"surface\"=>\"asphalt\",\"tunnel\"=>\"yes\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.2794761,
          53.4726425
        ],
        [
          -2.2794453,
          53.4727052
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6797b7f13446c40f73d"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 120,
    "osm_id": "2954151",
    "name": "Carrington Spur Roundabout",
    "highway": "primary",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": 7,
    "other_tags": "\"bicycle\"=>\"no\",\"foot\"=>\"no\",\"horse\"=>\"no\",\"junction\"=>\"roundabout\",\"lanes\"=>\"2\",\"lit\"=>\"yes\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"50 mph\",\"motorroad\"=>\"yes\",\"old_ref\"=>\"A6144(M)\",\"ref\"=>\"A6144\",\"surface\"=>\"asphalt\""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.3356624,
          53.441254
        ],
        [
          -2.3354015,
          53.4414335
        ],
        [
          -2.3353024,
          53.4414823
        ],
        [
          -2.3351726,
          53.4415197
        ],
        [
          -2.3350546,
          53.4415378
        ],
        [
          -2.3349539,
          53.4415401
        ],
        [
          -2.3348255,
          53.4415314
        ],
        [
          -2.3347273,
          53.4415155
        ],
        [
          -2.3346454,
          53.4414898
        ],
        [
          -2.3345723,
          53.4414612
        ],
        [
          -2.3345027,
          53.4414215
        ],
        [
          -2.3344338,
          53.4413635
        ],
        [
          -2.3343891,
          53.4413056
        ],
        [
          -2.3343492,
          53.441204
        ],
        [
          -2.3343534,
          53.4411219
        ],
        [
          -2.3344158,
          53.4410136
        ],
        [
          -2.3346322,
          53.4408458
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6797b7f13446c40f737"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 123,
    "osm_id": "3128714",
    "name": null,
    "highway": "motorway",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": 9,
    "other_tags": "\"bicycle\"=>\"no\",\"carriageway_ref\"=>\"A\",\"int_ref\"=>\"E 05\",\"lanes\"=>\"3\",\"lit\"=>\"no\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"70 mph\",\"maxspeed:type\"=>\"GB:motorway\",\"national_highways:area\"=>\"10\",\"oneway\"=>\"yes\",\"operator\"=>\"National Highways\",\"operator:wikidata\"=>\"Q5760006\",\"proposed"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.6372459,
          53.4752649
        ],
        [
          -2.6388304,
          53.4766533
        ],
        [
          -2.6405862,
          53.4779885
        ],
        [
          -2.6425177,
          53.4792311
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a3d6797b7f13446c40f73a"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 125,
    "osm_id": "3128721",
    "name": null,
    "highway": "motorway",
    "waterway": null,
    "aerialway": null,
    "barrier": null,
    "man_made": null,
    "railway": null,
    "z_order": 9,
    "other_tags": "\"bicycle\"=>\"no\",\"carriageway_ref\"=>\"A\",\"int_ref\"=>\"E 05\",\"lanes\"=>\"3\",\"lit\"=>\"yes\",\"maxheight\"=>\"default\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"70 mph\",\"maxspeed:type\"=>\"GB:motorway\",\"national_highways:area\"=>\"10\",\"oneway\"=>\"yes\",\"operator\"=>\"National Highways\",\"operator:wikidat"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -2.6980119,
          53.5348942
        ],
        [
          -2.6976861,
          53.5360286
        ],
        [
          -2.6975831,
          53.5364862
        ],
        [
          -2.6974973,
          53.5369331
        ],
        [
          -2.6973489,
          53.5378383
        ],
        [
          -2.6972311,
          53.538937
        ],
        [
          -2.6972099,
          53.5403599
        ],
        [
          -2.697288,
          53.5414513
        ],
        [
          -2.6973848,
          53.5422192
        ],
        [
          -2.697487,
          53.5428384
        ],
        [
          -2.6976637,
          53.543661
        ],
        [
          -2.6978317,
          53.5443402
        ],
        [
          -2.6979977,
          53.5448343
        ],
        [
          -2.6982133,
          53.5454732
        ],
        [
          -2.6984444,
          53.5460828
        ],
        [
          -2.6987022,
          53.5466993
        ],
        [
          -2.6989815,
          53.5473117
        ],
        [
          -2.6992917,
          53.5479157
        ],
        [
          -2.6996676,
          53.5486004
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}]
```

The error occurs specifically in the $geoWithin expression within the $lookup stage. It seems that the $geometry operator does not support using a variable ($$roadGeometry) as its value. However, I'm not sure how to resolve this error and achieve the desired result.

I would appreciate any assistance in understanding why I'm getting this error and how to properly use the $geoWithin operator within the $lookup stage to filter documents based on the intersection with the road geometries.

I just want to select those service roads which are within the houses
If I Write the query in it will be:

```
select a.* from manchaster_lines a inner join manchaster_polygons_v2 b on st_within(a.geom, b.geom) and a.highway = 'service' and b.building = 'house'
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample documents and expected output?

Comment: @ray I think now its clear